# Very simple jquery droppable hoverClass not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know this should be simple but I've stripped away almost everything.

My drop function fires and everything seems correct but the hoverClass does not change the div border and background.

I've tried this under Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. It has to be something I am missing but I cannot determine what.

**CSS:**

```
.drop-hover {
     background-color: yellow;
     border: 1px dotted red;
   }

#contactitems {
     background-color: white;
     width: 225px;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }

   #divactions {
     background-color: white;
     width: 375px;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     border: 1px solid green;
   }

   div.dvcontact {
     border: dotted;
     background-color: silver;
     border-width: thin;
     height: 80px;
     width: 165px;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }

   div.dvaction {
     border: solid 1px;
     background-color: aliceblue;
     height: 125px;
     width: 250px;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
```

**Javascript**

```
      $(".dvcontact").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
      });

      $(".dvaction").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
                var idmove = "" + ui.draggable.attr('id');
                var idinto = $(this).attr("id"); // "group";
                dropaction(idmove, idinto);
            },
      });

      function dropaction (fromid,toaction) {
            alert(fromid + " dropped into " + toaction);
        };
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactitems" class="dvcontactbox">
  <div id="cnt-1" class="dvcontact">Last, first
     <br />ABC Co.
     <br />1/10/2016 | none</div>
  <div id="cnt-2" class="dvcontact">Last, first
     <br />ABC Co.
     <br />1/10/2016 | none</div>
  <div id="cnt-3" class="dvcontact">Last, first
     <br />ABC Co.
     <br />1/10/2016 | none</div>
  <div id="cnt-4" class="dvcontact">Last, first
     <br />ABC Co.
     <br />1/10/2016 | none</div>
</div>

<div id="divactions" class="dvrightside">

   <div id="dvactgroup" class="dvaction">Group:</div>
   <div id="dvactschedule" class="dvaction">Schedule:</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbtoolkit/k7b6oh72/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you check to see if there are any errors in your console when you run this code? I also noticed your Fiddle was not set to a specific JQuery library. Also it is not wrapped properly.

Comment: I'm looking for where I do that in Fiddle. First time using that tool. I'm not getting errors in the developer tools in Chrome... well, on my actual page. I haven't looked on the Fiddle.

Comment: For Fiddle, in the script Panel, click 'Javascript' with the Gear, and you can select JQuery 2.1.4 and check off JQuery UI. This will add the sources to your fiddle so you can then make use of JQuery UI. The next time you Run or Update, it will be available.

Comment: Okay.. I used the "External Resources" in the left column. But if they have it built in and it provides greater clarity, I'll use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class *is* being added; however it's a CSS issue. The properties are being overridden.

The problem is that the selector `div.dvcontact` is more specific than the selector `.drop-hover`. This results in the background-color and border added with the selector `div.dvcontact` overriding the properties added with `.drop-hover`.

You could increase [the specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector `.drop-hover` to `.dvaction.drop-hover` or `.ui-droppable.drop-hover`. In doing so, it will override the existing background color and border:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xzq3gsj4/)

```
.ui-droppable.drop-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Here is the calculated specificity of each selector:

- `div.dvcontact` - 0, 0, 1, 1 (class selector and type selector)
- `.drop-hover` - 0, 0, 1, 0 (class selector)
- `.ui-droppable.drop-hover` - 0, 0, 2, 0 (two class selectors)
- `.dvaction.drop-hover` - 0, 0, 2, 0 (two class selectors as well)

Due to the cascading nature of CSS, if the selectors have the same specificity, the one that appears last (i.e., lowest in the stylesheet) will override the previous one(s) since the stylesheet is parsed from top to bottom.

Side Notes:

- Read more about [CSS specificity at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
- There are CSS specificity calculators such as [this one](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

Comment: I was just typing up an answer that talked about this. Props on being faster and more accurate.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought I did yesterday. It's been accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

$(".dvcontact").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
      });

```
  $(".dvaction").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
            var idmove = "" + ui.draggable.attr('id');
            var idinto = $(this).attr("id"); // "group";
            dropaction(idmove, idinto);
        }
  });

  function dropaction (fromid,toaction) {
        alert(fromid + " dropped into " + toaction);
    };
```

Comment: should remove comma after drop function

Comment: Sadly, this answer doesn't actually answer the poster's CSS priority woes.

Comment: but i found this mistake that 's why i highlighted it

Comment: That's what comments are for.